# Issue in Integration GTM (Google Tag Manager ) android

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

i want to implement Google Tag Manager in android app so i set followwing code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String CONTAINER_ID = "GTM-YYYY";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);

     tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);

    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending =
            tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(CONTAINER_ID,
                    R.raw.gtm_default_container);

    pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
            ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
            if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e("CuteAnimals", "failure loading container");
                displayErrorToUser(R.string.load_error);
                return;
            }
            ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            ContainerLoadedCallback.registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
            containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerLoadedCallback());
            startMainActivity();
         }
     }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}
```

i also set google play library in my gradle file as below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pkg.android.demo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
 }

  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

When i put above code **ContainerLoadedCallback** clas not found as below image

[image]

Any idea how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This methods are from example. You have to implement them by yourself if you want.
You can also comment **//** them and it will work fine. Remove lines with errors.

This classes are shown here to show what can you do with your container.

Answer (score 0):

You can find these classes in the cuteanimal sample. Go to your directory where sdk is located.....  /extras/google/google_play_services/tagmanager/cuteanimals